# Make ruby automacially find the values for the proxy/authentication settings for http?

Tags: ruby, windows, http, proxy, mechanize-ruby

I'm using the ruby gem Mechanize to access a website through a proxy and it's working find I'm just wondering if it's possible to have ruby automatically fill in my proxy settings.

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new do|a|
  a.set_proxy('proxy', port, 'YOUR_USER_NAME', 'YOUR_PASS')
end
```

I know how to get the username and proxy but not the password as the proxy requires authentication.

```
ENV['username']
ENV['http_proxy']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a variable `HTTP_PROXY` in your environment containing all you need, for instance :

```
HTTP_PROXY = http://username:password@proxyserver.domain.com
```

Then, you should have a method where you can pass this string, or if you don't, some parsing will do the trick.

Comment: Right now I just have my proxy/port in the 'HTTP_PROXY' and was hoping there was some other way than modify it.  It would work on my pc but if I used the script on another s they might not have the 'HTTP_PROXY'.

Comment: You get the gold since it actually answers my question even if my solution was something else.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I needed was:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new do|a|
 a.set_proxy('proxy', port, 'YOUR_USER_NAME')
end
```

I guess I just assumed that I would need the password but it looks like you only need your username.!  Perhaps mechanize uses NTLM or some such?

Comment: Note I actually use ENV['username'] for YOUR_USER_NAME